# Brother HL-5450DN disconnected from Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. How to fix?

Tags: 16.04, printing

I have a desktop that worked great with the Brother HL-5450DN.  About two weeks ago, I received and error message from my new desktop that indicated a problem with the CPU or motherboard.  I unplugged the computer, then counted to ten, and plugged it back in.  It started up fine with no more problems.  Since then, I have not been connected to the printer mentioned above.  I would like to print things now and can not figure out how to regain control of my systems.  Any thoughts on what has happened?

Comment: please add how your printer is connected. (USB, WiFi ...)

Comment: The computer and printer are hardwired into a network

Comment: I assume both are connected to a router or sth. Is the printer available in the network?

Comment: sth?  I have a yellow Cat5 type cable for ethernet and the printer is available and responds to other computers on the network.  I believe mine lost connection and am attempting to reset it.

Comment: I have reset the connection and all is well.  thanks for you time.